# Compare data in two different tables in kdb

Tags: kdb

I would like to compare data for two different instances for the same table.
What I think is I can compare the null values in the table, however, I am not sure how I can do it to generalize to all tables.

For example:
    This is the table I have:

```
a:([]a:0n 2 3;b:"a", " ","c")
```

I am trying to use the below code to count null value for the all the columns:

```
{count where (null a[x]) =1b} each  cols a
```

How am I able to use this to generalize to all tables? and use the code to compare to the remote tables?

```
h: hopen `:2001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing the data from the remote table can be quite tricky, and it will depend on a lot of factors like table size, whether the table is partitioned etc.

Assuming the tables are in memory and you are using the null checks as table signature, you can execute this on the remote session and then compare it with your local instance.

````
/Remote service - port 2001
q)table1:([]col1:0n 2 3 0n ;col2:"a", " ","ca")
q)table2:([]col3:1 2 0n 4 ;col4:```b`)

/local
q)table1:([]col1:0n 2 3 0n ;col2:"a", " ","ca")
q)table2:([]col3:1 2 0n 4 ;col4:```b`d)   //different from remote
q)table3:([]col5:1 2 0n 4 ;col6:```b`d)    //local table

q)f: { tables[]!{[t] (), {sum null x} each flip 0!value t}each tables[]}  //tables unkeyed

q)remote:`::2001(f;::)
q)remote 
(`s#`table1`table2)!((`col1`col2)!2 1;(`col3`col4)!1 3)

q)local:f[]
q)local
(`s#`table1`table2`table3)!((`col1`col2)!2 1;(`col3`col4)!1 2;(`col5`col6)!1 2)

q)remote~'local   //only table1 signature matches
(`table1`table2`table3)!100b
````

Comment: This will only confirm that the schemas are identical, not that the values within the tables are identical

Comment: `f` will not work on keyed tables, could modify to `value 0!t` to get round it.

Comment: Thanks for the input @ThomasSmyth, updated the code.

Comment: will check next Monday. Thanks!!